# Is there a way to convert categories of posts into tags?

Tags: wordpress.com, wordpress.com-tags

I currently use categories to tag my posts but I found it not as convenient as using tags. So I want to convert all current categories into tags. How can I do this?

Comment: For wordpress specific questions you can also try this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **Categories and Tags Converter**.

http://yourblog.wordpress.com/wp-admin/admin.php?import=wp-cat2tag

Also converts Tags to Categories.